# Why $\{Y_m=\sup\{x_k:k\ge m\}\}$ is bounded below?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{x_k\}$ be a bounded sequence in $\Bbb R$, and let $Y_m=\sup\{x_k:k\ge m\}$. Show that $\lim \limits_{m\to \infty}Y_m$ exists.

I know that $\{Y_m\}$ is a decreasing sequence so $\lim \limits_{m\to \infty}Y_m=\inf_\limits{m}Y_m$. But I don't know how to show that $\{Y_m\}$ is bounded below. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Isn't the sequence given to be bounded? :-)

Comment: $x_k \geq a$ for all $k$ implies $Y_m \geq a$ for all $m$.

Comment: I got it, thanks